# mp3 Quality and size manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, mp3

I'm looking for a way (a class, sorcerry) to reduce the size of MP3 file.
I know MP3 is already optimized, for minimal size, so I wonder if I can somehow reduce the quality (maybe bitrate) so i'll have a tradeoff between quality and file size....

My server side language is PHP,
Thanks alot,
Yanipan

Comment: What server are you running your PHP on? If you are running on Linux you may wish to look into using FFMPEG or similar and then just using PHP to call this service (using exec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comment kissmyfase, best way is exec ffmpeg:

```
<?php
  exec("ffmpeg -b 128k -i input.mp3 output.mp3");
?>
```

or as answer sbrattla:

```
<?php
  exec("lame --abr 128 input.mp3 output.mp3");
?>
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the ultra-fast replies... i'm not familier with using such services on linux server (i'm using a linux server). Any chance you could elaborate a bit on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you need to convert your MP3 files to lower quality. However, I'm not aware of any PHP libraries capable of doing this. If you are allowed to install applications on the server you are at, then I'd recommend LAME which does a good job at converting MP3 files. It's also quick.

You could kick of LAME as an external program from PHP to do the work.